Rewrite Many Query String In Url To Origin URL Wordpress PHP
I have some problem need to be solved ! My site using Wordpress with Gtranslate . So i have million link to be solved .
I want rewrite url query string by PHP Wordpress , from here
https://domain/bs/page/150/?-2-февруари-2020-г
https://domain/bg/page/86/?archive_query=title&alphabet_filter
https://domain/nl/page/138/?video_index=2
https://domain/ar/page/166/?-Dlatego-jest-świetna
https://domain/ar/page/267/?video_embed=94892
https://domain/cs/page/218/?alphabet_filter=T&archive_query=latest
https://domain/sv/page/4/?-Nie-baw-się-ze-mną
https://domain/pt/page/167/?-Jeon,-czerwiec-2021
https://domain/ms/page/230/?archive_query=latest&alphabet_filter
https://domain/ar/page/120/?sid=2
https://domain/ur/page/55/?msclkid=7dc975ebc56911ec84e42d13d691de5f
https://domain/el/page/225/?-movie-for-watching-part-2
https://domain/pl/page/54/?alphabet_filter&archive_query=title
https://domain/ja/page/200/?sid=2&bsa_pro_id=2&bsa_pro_url=1

To This ( it many more query string , i can't put it all to here , this is just few spam link )
https://domain/bs/page/150/
https://domain/bg/page/86/
https://domain/nl/page/138/
https://domain/ar/page/166/
https://domain/ar/page/267/
https://domain/cs/page/218/
https://domain/sv/page/4/
https://domain/pt/page/167/
https://domain/ms/page/230/
https://domain/ar/page/120/
https://domain/ur/page/55/
https://domain/el/page/225/
https://domain/pl/page/54/
https://domain/ja/page/200/

It mean i dont want query string show on my url , this url with query string will be indexed on google , and i dont want this , this url with query string is spam and make my index link bigger than i have .
And remember , exclude search query string from rewrite url .
https://domain/?s=abc+test
https://domain/page/2/?s=abc+test

Sorry , my english is bad .
It is difficult to explain the problem.

Have you tried using strtok like shown in this similar question? In your case, try strtok("https://domain/ja/page/200/?sid=2&bsa_pro_id=2&bsa_pro_url=1") it returns "https://domain/ja/page/200/" just like you wanted

i dont know code bro :(

I'm sorry I'm not familiar with using PHP in Wordpress. But if you managed to write and run PHP code in Wordpress, you can just write the code like this: strtok("https://domain/?s=abc+test", "?"). Just replace https://domain/?s=abc+test with any URLs you want

I solved my problem with this functions , you can add this function to Snippet Plugin ! If u want to add to functions.php theme , you need to set if be is_admin before run this script
add_action('init', 'remove_url');

function remove_url(){
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if(str_contains($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "?s=") === FALSE AND str_contains($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "?") === TRUE){
        $url_remove = strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '?');
        //echo $url_remove . "</br>";
        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
        header("Location: https://domain/$url_remove");
        exit(); 
    }
    
}


I believe it would be best for you to do all that from within nginx rather than bury rewrites to wordpress.
